# Is the Symfony 2.8 "page creation" docs missing a step?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

After using occasional Symfony components, I finally decided to make a real Symfony project and installed Symfony 2.8, and went to the [page creation docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/page_creation.html) and followed the steps where it said to make the

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
```

file.  I did that.  It did say that you need to make a route, but it didn't say how to do that before it said to test it out.  So I tested it out as it said and got a

```
No route found for "GET /lucky/number"
```

Error.  I assume I need to make the route, but shouldn't that page show that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is explained in the first code block in the document: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/page_creation.html#creating-a-page-route-and-controller

If this doesn't work, there must be something wrong. A couple things to check:

- Does your `app/config/routing.yml` contains the 3 lines below?

  ```
  app:
      resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
      type:     annotation
  ```
- Does your `src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php` file contain `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`?
- Does the multiline comment before the method start with `/**` (instead of the normal `/*`)? And is it directly followed by the method definition, without any empty line and such?

Comment: Yep.  Checked all those things. The [LuckyController.php code](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/page_creation.html) is copied exactly from the demo docs.  And the routing.yml file is exactly as you described by the default install.  
I don't know if this matters, but I'm running Symfony in a MAMP environment.  It's the only thing "unusual" about my install, since nothing people have told me to do works yet, I'm trying to figure out what else I may be doing differently than others.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Hmm, can you try running the `php app/console debug:router` command to check if the route is available? Maybe you did not have the AppBundle registered in AppKernel?

Comment: Running the debug:router returns a table with the headers Name,Method,Scheme,Host, and Path.  And 14 rows, the bottom of which is homepage.  Nothing about "Lucky" in there.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed does `src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php` start with the `<?php` start tag? Otherwise, it isn't parsed as PHP code.

Comment: OMG.  Thank you.  That was the problem.  Thank you, Wouter J.

Answer (score 0):

The route is set by the `@Route` annotation in your controller (there are other ways to do it, but this is the default way that works for most cases). So it is created in the example code on line 11:

```
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
```

This is also explained on the documentation you mentioned:

> The `@Route` above `numberAction()` is called an *annotation* and it defines the URL pattern. You can also write routes in YAML (or other formats): read about this in the [routing](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/routing.html) chapter.

You *may* need to clear your cache if it doesn't work right away, delete everything under `app/cache/dev/` or run this from your command line:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: I cleared the cache, it still doesn't work.  I'll try reading that routing chapter, but I didn't think that was necessary for the "first page creation" demo.

Comment: @IgorPantović, yep... The annotation is exactly copy/pasted from the [LuckyController.php code](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/page_creation.html).